# Linux screen tool - Run command on session created in cron

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, gnu-screen

In crontab (edited via command `crontab -e` on `me` user), I have written:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -mdS test
*/6 * * * * /home/me/RunDFB.sh
```

I'm using `RunDFB.sh` to check, is my console app (which is running in `screen` session) is working correctly - if it isn't, script is killing my app, and runs it again, by following command:

```
/usr/bin/screen -S test -X stuff "$SCREEN_CMD"`echo -ne '\015'`
```

When crontab is creating session (ex. `@reboot /usr/bin/screen -mdS test`), script can't run command from `$SCREEN_CMD` variable (without any error. It's just not executing), but when I'm creating session by myself (in this same way as crontab - `/usr/bin/screen -mdS test`), script runs my `$SCREEN_CMD` in the `screen` session without any problem.

What am I doing wrong?

.

P.S. I tried even combine this two `screen` commands (`/usr/bin/screen -m -d -S test -X stuff "$SCREEN_CMD"`echo -ne '\015'``), but then (regardless if I input command by myself or it runs by crontab), I get error message:

> No screen session found.

.

@edit:
Here is content of my `$SCREEN_CMD` variable

```
SCREEN_CMD="dotnet run --project /home/pi/DFB/DFB.csproj"
```

Comment: Where have you defined `SCREEN_CMD`?

Comment: I don't think, its important to write this variable's contetnt, because it is working when I create new screen session by myself, but OK. I added this definition.